# JOptionPane.showOptionDialog returning wrong value?

Tags: java, swing

i got the following java code

```
 Icon icoR = new ImageIcon("src/resources/Republica.png");
 Icon icoI = new ImageIcon("src/resources/Imperio.png");
 JButton botRep = new JButton("Jedi", icoR);
 JButton botImp = new JButton("Sith", icoI);
 Object[] options = {botRep, botImp};
 //Object[] options = {"Jedi","Sith"};
 int i = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
     null,
     "Question","Title",
     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
     null,options,options[0]);
 System.out.println(i);
```

and im trying to retrieve the selected value from the optionDialog with icon buttons. Problem is, that althought dialog and buttons themselves are properly shown, whenever the buttons are clicked.. nothign happens, and the println statement isnt executed... until i click on the X to close the dialog, and regardless of what i have clicked before.. an 1 is printed as result. Oddly enough, if i change the options array to the regular (text only) one that appears commented in the code, the dialog behaves as one would expect returning the 0-based index of the chosen option. Any hints on what could be wrong here?
thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, try passing the icons themselves - note to self, typing on the ipad sucks

Comment: @MadProgrammer, just like me trying to type without wearing my glasses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you just pass the Icons, the option pane will create the buttons for you:

```
Object[] options = {icoR, icoI};
```

So I guess if you pass the buttons it assumes that you will handle the closing of the option pane yourself.

As a work around you can use the [Compound Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) class to create an Icon containing text and your image.

You might also want to use the `Text Icon` which you can also find from the above link. When you create the TextIcon you will probably need to use:

```
setFont( UIManager.getFont("Button.font") );
```

to set the font of the `TextIcon` to be the same as the button.

Comment: I see that when the option objects are components, then it should work as expected. Why is that we should pass the icons instead? Can you please explain?

Comment: `I see that when the option objects are components, then it should work as expected.` - The API just says they are rendered properly. It doesn't say that if you use a button the ActionListener will be added to the button automatically.  I'm just suggesting an alternative.

Comment: Certainly, passing only the icons makes it work, thank you very much!